# There are errors in your xml file: not well-formed (invalid token) ? error

Tags: javascript, node.js

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<crc error_type=”1|2” error_code=”{numeric}”>{message}</crc>`

this is the xml that i try to parse to json because I need to update if there is an error with an error code .... please if u could help

error message from xml2json : throw new Error('There are errors in your xml file: ' + parser.getError());

There are errors in your xml file: not well-formed (invalid token)

thanks

Comment: Your XML looks like it has non-standard double-quote characters, like fancy "smart" quotes instead of simple basic double-quotes

Comment: One of many examples of why a word processor is not an IDE.

Comment: "1.0" vs ”1|2” look at the Quotes.